# Create a matrix with counts - hive sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there a way to achieve this with hive? I need to count users per segment.

**I have a table:**

user1, categoryA

user1, categoryB

user2, categoryC

**And the desired output would be:**

----------------- Category A, Category B, Category C

Category A --   1 1 0

Category B --      1 1 0

Category C --        0 0 1

Answer (score 0):

For static set of categories, this is possible:

```
with your_data as(
select stack (6, 
'user1', 'categoryA',
'user1', 'categoryB',
'user2', 'categoryC',
'user2', 'categoryC',
'user3', 'categoryA',
'user4', 'categoryA'                  
) as (`user`, category)
)

select 
      category, sum(catA) as CategoryA, sum(catB) as CategoryB, sum(catC) as CategoryC
from
(
  select `user` , category, --each user counted once per category
          max(case when category='categoryA' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by `user`) as catA,
          max(case when category='categoryB' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by `user`) as catB,
          max(case when category='categoryC' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by `user`) as catC
  from your_data
   group by  `user` , category
)s
group by Category
order by category
```

Result:

```
category    categorya   categoryb   categoryc
categoryA      3           1           0
categoryB      1           1           0
categoryC      0           0           1
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way without having to hardcode that mapping manually? I have over 100 segments

Comment: @Sapehi I do not know how to do it without hardcoding. dynamic columns are not possible in Hive.Maybe it is possible to collect some map or array... instead of selecting columns.